# What is the best way acces active directory in an ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory

I created an ASP.NET core application and want to access Active Directory from this application. I want to create a new user account in Active Directory, create groups and add and remove members to the group.

In the past I would have done this via the following Namespace:

System.DirectoryServices

as described in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

This does not seem to work in .NET Core. It seems like this is not compatible with .NET Core. What is the recommeneded way of using Active Directory in .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet package System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement will be needed. Visual Studio was not suggesting the package on its own. Also, this of course only works for Windows, as Active Directory is proprietary to Windows. This is the appropriate `using` statement:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

I was able to access our Active Directory using this code in .NET 6.0:

```
var AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.local");
```

Then, I wanted access to the phone number for each user in a certain Group, so I used this:

```
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(AD, "TestGroup").GetMembers();
```

To find a specific user (the type conversion appears to work, at least well enough for my scenario):

```
var user = (UserPrincipal)group.First(x => x.SamAccountName.ToUpper() == "TestUser".ToUpper());
```

To [add a **User**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) or [add a **Group**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), use the example code below:

```
UserPrincipal usr = new UserPrincipal(ctx); 
usr.Name = "Jim Daly";
usr.Description = "This is the user account for Jim Daly";  
usr.EmailAddress = "jimdaly@fabrikam.com";  
usr.SetPassword("securelyStoredPassword");  
usr.Save();
```

Use `.Save()` for Groups also.

Comment: Tryed here on .NET 7 Core and don't works. Are you used some package ? What are usings for this ?

Comment: I find now. Need "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" nuget package and this is compatible just on Windows

Comment: Sorry, yes I should have included the NuGet package and `using` statement, as Visual Studio was not suggesting it for me either. I will edit my Answer to include.

Comment: But has other options to run on linux too, it's exclusive this package don't work on other platforms